# Test if a Linq query return values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a little problem. I have a property who return me a List and I want to do a linq query on it in order to test if I match with another object.

I'm not sure to be very clear, so here is my code.

I'm first try this :

```
if ((from item in MyList where item.Keys == myObject.Keys select item).Any())
    //Some stuff
```

But no result.
So then I try this :

```
if (MyList.Where(item => item.Keys == myObject.Keys).Any())
    //Some stuff
```

And no more result...

I don't understand where is the problem.
Oh yes, before question about it : Yes I'm sure to match between my list and my object ;)

EDIT : I try too with `.Equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: what do you mean "no more result"? what problem you got?

Comment: Are you sure MYList is having all the data?

Comment: Question is not very clar - you want to check if any of items should contain any key which match any keys of your object?

Comment: MyList has an object with the datas I want, I said it _I'm sure to match between my list and my object_

Comment: @Shadam clarify your question. Also define what is Keys and what is match?

Comment: @Shadam - Looks to me like you want `Intersect()` and then `Any()`

Comment: No, I want `Any()`, it's for see if the list contains an object with same values. Anyway, newStackExchangeInstance gave me the solution below ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SequenceEqual` to compare enumerables:

```
if (MyList.Where(item => item.Keys.SequenceEqual(myObject.Keys)).Any())
```

Comment: Here the winner ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check with:

```
if(MyList.Any(item => item.Keys.SequenceEqual(myObject.Keys))) {

}
```

or

```
if(MyList.Any(item => item.Keys.Length == myObject.Keys.Length 
           && item.Keys.Intersect(myObject.Keys).Count() == item.Keys.Length)) {

}
```

You can't compare properties of different objects of type List with `==` or `Equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ((from item in MyList where myObject.Contains(item) select item).Any())
```

Comment: It can't works, they are not the same objects.